# Did US make any significant fiscal changes following Panama Papers disclosures?

Tags: united-states, taxes, policy, panama-papers

The Panama Papers disclosure was a huge scandal, so there were [many reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panama_Papers#Allegations.2C_reactions.2C_and_investigations). [This article](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2016/may/06/panama-papers-us-launches-crackdown-on-international-tax-evasion) illustrates Barack Obama's reaction to this:

> Barack Obama is launching a crackdown on international tax evasion in
>   response to recent disclosures in the Panama Papers revealing the
>   scale of offshore financial activity.
>
> In a series of initiatives announced by the White House on Thursday
>   night, the president will take executive action to close loopholes
>   used by foreigners in the US and call on Congress to pass legislation.
>
> Though the later steps may hit political obstacles in an election
>   year, the package of measures are among the most comprehensive
>   responses yet to the Panama Papers revelations, disclosed by a
>   consortium of international journalists including the Guardian.
>
> [..]
>
> - immediate executive action to combat money laundering, terrorist financing, and tax evasion with tighter transparency rules
> - new Treasury rules closing a loophole allowing foreigners to hide financial activity behind anonymous entities in the US.
> - stricter “customer due diligence” rules for banks handling money on behalf of clients

More than a year has passed since that moment.

**Question: Did US make any significant fiscal changes following Panama Papers disclosures?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's over a year old, but I came here to also ask this question.
As far as I can find in my research, [the US actually went in the opposite of the desired direction](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2016/04/05/how-the-u-s-became-one-of-the-worlds-biggest-tax-havens/?utm_term=.75c860b97755), and helped make itself more appealing as a tax haven.

From the linked article quoting James Henry, a senior advisor to the Tax Justice Network:

> The U.S. has an onshore haven industry that is as secretive as anywhere, Henry said. "[Americans] discovered that they really don’t need to go to Panama."

I can't find any indication that any of the steps recommended by Barack Obama have taken place, in the US or in many other countries.

---

**Update**: as of today (12/6/2018), [charges have been brought up over the Panama Papers in the US.](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/12/04/business/panama-papers-indictment.html)
Apparently these sorts of things take some time to establish a case.

Comment: That is a very interesting article that also mentions Foreign Account Tax Compliance Act (FATCA) implemented in 2010 which seems to fight against tax cheats.

Comment: @Alexei added update to reflect current state of this situation.